# Fixing application icon question mark when locking to launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

After downloading an application containing an executable and launching said executable, you are able to lock the application to the launcher. Sometimes the program's icon is not present and instead only a question mark appears. How do you change the icon in the panel?

<sub>Note: this applies specifically for applications not downloaded through Ubuntu's application manager.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For a downloaded program you can use Nautilus to access the executable's properties. First unlock the program from the launcher, then open the executables containing folder:

[Program Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hekQF.png)

Right click on the executable and select Properties:

[Properties Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9roz3.png)

Left click the icon square and select the program's proper icon. Restart the program and lock it to the launcher.